# React table with JSON subdocument data only

Tags: reactjs

I have nested arrays in JSON object that comes from CosmosDB. I have 3 subdocuments in the JSON which I want to display that data into a react table for each subdocument. How can we map each subdocument to a React Table Rows?
Below is the screenshot that I am expecting.

[image]

below is JSON data

```
[
  {
    "id": "DD3",
    "studydate": "DDD",
    "studydescription": "DD3 Description",
    "studyname": "DD3",
    "table1": [
      {
        "no": "1",
        "name": "DD3 Name",
        "date": "Krishna",
        "description\r": "1111\r"
      },
      {
        "no": "2",
        "name": "DD3 Nam2",
        "date": "Test2",
        "description\r": "2222\r"
      },
      {
        "no": "3",
        "name": "DD3 Name3",
        "date": "Test3",
        "description\r": "3333"
      }
    ],
    "table2": [
      {
        "No": "2",
        "Study Field1": "21",
        "Study Field2": "22",
        "Study Field3\r": "23"
      }
    ],
    "table3": [
      {
        "No": "3",
        "Study Field5": "T31",
        "Study Field6": "T32",
        "Study Field7": "T33",
        "Study Field 8\r": "T34"
      }
    ],
    "_rid": "QeNcANZFTTIKAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/QeNcAA==/colls/QeNcANZFTTI=/docs/QeNcANZFTTIKAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"33002e92-0000-0200-0000-5fa6fe320000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1604779570
  }
]
```

Comment: Is react table a custom component you found on github/npm?

Comment: I want use react-table or DataGrid from material-ui or any simple solution also OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a basic example of how you could generate the rows off JSON. I am just using basic HTML to keep it simple as the prop names will change depending what component you go with but same principle.

JavaScript for filtering and pushing to table array.

```
   let rowArr = [];
   Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
      rowArr.push(data[key])
   })
```

HTML/JS

```
    <table>
        <!-- This should loop through rows allowing you to get row values -->
        {rowArr.map(row => (
            <tr key={row}>
                <td>{row.Task}</td>
                <td>{row.Description}</td>
                <td>{row.Assignee}</td>
                <td>{row.Client}</td>
                <td>{row.Contact}</td>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </table>
```

Here is a simple JSON structure

```
let data =
{ 
    1:{
       Task: "Software",
       Description:  "Mockup designs",
       Assignee: "John Doe",
       Client: "Mark Wong",
       Contact: "mark.wong@gmail.com"
      }
}
```

Comment: Hello Alex, I updated accordingly. I can get elements from main properties from table1 from JSON.. how can we extend above logic to table1 in JSON?

Comment: But i want to assign rowArr.table1 to a react-table "rows"

Comment: But i want to assign rowArr.table1 to an object/array. so that i can use that wherever required?

Comment: You should be able to no problem, the important part is that you filter out the correct data in appropriate structures (arrays) before passing to the react-table props. For example, you don't want to loop the headers with the table data because it won't work, ideally you'd display headers once and subsequent data underneath, I could see you using two arrays and doing similar as I have done above but one for headers and one for table rows. @AnandaKrishna

Comment: I will note for react-table, you have to manually generate your headers and columns, you would pass rows and headers props to it that you filtered out to be the correct JSON. It also doesn't handle huge lists without great optimization so paging is a must for large datasets. @AnandaKrishna Hope this helps. If you will be handling fairly large data sets, need filtering, searching, inline column editing, I would go with react-data-grid as react-table is more for viewing data then modifications